# multiprocessing 'apply_async' execution in if-else block

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have one test code for apply_async. Why 'apply_sync' of else in test_call doesn't get executed? If "if-else" block gets replaced by same 'apply_async' calls, both gets executed.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool


def _execute(l):
    res = []
    for i in l:
        res.append(i * i)

    return res


class TestMulti(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.l = []

    def test_call(self):
        p = Pool(2)

        def _join(res):
            self.l += res
        for i in range(2):
            if i % 2 == 0:
                p.apply_async(_execute, args=([1, 2, 3],),callback=_join)
            else:
                p.apply_async(_execute, args=([4, 5, 6]), callback=_join)

        p.close()
        p.join()
        print self.l


if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = TestMulti()
    t.test_call()
```

O/P: [1, 4 , 9]

Expected O/P : [1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36]

Comment: you are missing a coma in p.apply_async(_execute, args=([4, 5, 6]), callback=_join)

it should be p.apply_async(_execute, args=([4, 5, 6],), callback=_join)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the missing comma mentioned by Vikas, you also have an extraneous close paren at the end of the first apply_async line.

Fixing these two issues and running your code, I get the output you expect.

Fixing only the paren and not the comma, I get the output you describe seeing.

Comment: The extra paren was typo. The comma in args was the issue. Thnx.